# How to replace document.getElementById('file-uploader') with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to replace `document.getElementById('file-uploader')` with jQuery?

just

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('file-uploader');
```

into jQuery expression?

Thanks!!!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myElement = $('#file-uploader');
```

Comment: Note that this will not return the native DOM element, but a jQuery result list. That is arguably more convenient, if you are going to continue calling jQuery stuff on it, but not a 100% drop-in replacement for the old code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the native DOM element?

```
var myElement = $('#file-uploader')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

To do that with jQuery, you would use:

```
var myElement = jQuery('#file-uploader');
```

The selectors are similar to extended CSS selectors.

If you are in the right context, you can use the shorthand:

```
var myElement = $('#file-uploader');
```

Answer (score 1):

var myElement = $("#file-uploader")

Answer (score 1):

```
var myElement = $('#file-uploader');
```